# Get the decrypted content of the section in web.config without saving

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, encryption, configuration, web-config

How can I get the content of the decrypted webconfig section before it saves the decrypted file: `confg.Save()`?

```
Dim confg As System.Configuration.Configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath)
Dim confgSect As ConfigurationSection = confg.GetSection("section")
If confgSect.SectionInformation.IsProtected Then
    confgSect.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection()
    confg.Save()
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim confg As System.Configuration.Configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath)
Dim confgSect As ConfigurationSection = confg.GetSection("section")
If confgSect.SectionInformation.IsProtected Then
    confgSect.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection()
    Dim xml As New System.Xml.XmlDocument

    Dim node As System.Xml.XmlNodeList

    Dim str As String
    Dim answer As String

    str = confgSect.SectionInformation.GetRawXml()

    xml.LoadXml("<ROOT>" + str + "</ROOT>")
    node = xml.GetElementsByTagName("TagnameHere")
    answer= node(0).Attributes(1).Value

End If
```

My section in the webcobfig contains multiple tags, so I used xml to get each tag and get its value as an attribute.